# how to insert a squence with slight modification in a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a fixed list and a fixed size numpy array.

```
data = [10,20,30]
arr = np.zeros(9)
```

I want to insert the `data` in NumPy `arr` with some slight modification so that the expected output should look like this:

```
arr = [10, 20, 30, 9, 22, 32, 13, 16, 28]
```

the difference between the values can be in the range of `(-5, 5)`
my attept was:

```
import numpy as np
data = [10,20,30]
dataArr = np.zeros(9)
for i in range(9):
    for j in data:
        dataArr[3*i:3*(i+1)] = random.randint(int(j - 5), int(j + 5))
dataArr
```

but it gives me this output:

```
array([34., 34., 34., 33., 33., 33., 35., 35., 35.])
```

can somebody please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```py
dataArr[3*i:3*(i+1)] = value
```

You are setting the entire range to `value`. In fact your indices even go beyond the range of `dataArr`, even though it doesn't raise an exception.
See after execution :

```py
print(dataArr[3*i:3*(i+1)])
# output:
# []
```

Iterate over the values of `data`, and modify the three corresponding values in `dataArr` by doing so:

```py
nbOfRepetitions = 3
dataArr = np.zeros(len(data)*nbOfRepetitions)
for i in range(len(data)):
    dataArr[i] = data[i]
    for j in range(1, nbOfRepetitions):
        dataArr[i+len(data)*j] = random.randint(int(data[i] - 5), int(data[i] + 5))
```

Where `nbOfRepetitions` is the number of time you want to have data in dataArr (this includes the non-modified copy at the start).
This gives the expected result.

```
array([10., 20., 30., 12., 18., 30., 10., 24., 28.])
```

Edited to generalize for different sizes for `data` and `dataArr`.

Comment: yeah I know it should give out of index error but I am running it in jupyter notebook that's why may be it is not giving that error and by the way thank you so much.  but still there is one error in this one, first 3 values if you look should be same as data than after those first three value the random function should come into play

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice that bit, I modified the answer.

Comment: yeah this is now perfect, thank you so much

Comment: hey if the total number of elements in the data is 10 and size of dataArr is 40 then what will be this [i+3*j] ? becoz in my case it is giving the index out of bound error

Comment: Edited answer. I should have made it more general in the first place, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to skip the first `N` items that are already in your `data` array, you can change your inner loop and access indices to something like:

```
import random
import numpy as np
MAX_LENGTH = 9
data = [10,20,30]
dataArr = np.zeros(MAX_LENGTH)
for i in range(MAX_LENGTH):
    for j in range(len(data),MAX_LENGTH):
        dataArr[j] = random.randint((min(data) - 5), (max(data) + 5))
dataArr[0:len(data)] = data

# output:
array([10., 20., 30., 28., 31., 17., 30., 30., 10.])
```

Comment: this is not giving out the expected output

Comment: dont forget to recover the original items with the last line in `dataArr[0:len(data)] = data
`

Comment: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  2.,  5.,  4., 10.,  9.,  4.]) this is the output  after running your program

Comment: ahhhh but still it is not the same, random values should be from data values with the minor difference of (-5,+5) range. output should be like this arr = [10, 20, 30, 9, 22, 32, 13, 16, 28]

Comment: data[0] +5 or -5 then data[1] -5 or +5 and data[2] -5 or +5

Comment: ok so you actually want something slightly different than what you are currently calculating. see again, i edited answer

Comment: range is not from (min(data), max(data), its should be actually from data elements like one of the above ans suggest but I can use both of your ways, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Other than [above solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68558720/7035448), this can be also one more way

```py
import numpy as np
(
    (np.random.randint(10, size=(3, 3)) - 5) +
    np.array([10, 20, 30])
).reshape(-1)
```

First get 3x3 matrix of random integers from 0-10 and subtract 5 to get from -5 to 5

Before adding `np.array([10, 20, 30])` will be broadcasted along 0 axis like `np.array([10, 20, 30])[np.newaxis, :]` and towards end flattening

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up your array to use integer types:

```
dataArr = np.zeros(9, dtype=int)
```